# Angular - Wait for a promise and onload method to be completed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I have following two methods, one http promise and one that is triggered in the view (with directive) when the iframe is loaded:

```
    $scope.iframeOnLoad = function(){
        console.log('the iframe is done loading');            
    };

    $scope.getPage = function(uuid){
        pagesFactory.getPage(uuid)
            .success(function(data){
                console.log('page data is done loading');                   
            })
            .error(function(error){                
                growl.error('This page does not exist.');
            });

    };
```

When both methods are done, I want to add some initialize magic. But I can't figure out the best way to wait for both. If both methods where promises, I could just wait for them, but since the iframeOnLoad is only triggered when the iframe is done loading..

The directive looks as following:

```
.directive('ngOnload', function () {
      return {
          restrict: "A",
          scope: {
              callback: "&ngOnload"
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs){
              var location;
              if(element.length > 0 && element[0].contentWindow){
                  location = element[0].contentWindow.location;
              }else{
                  location = undefined;
              }
              element.on("load", function(){
                  scope.callback({
                      contentLocation:location
                  });
              });
          }
      }
});
```

Hope someone can enlighten me :)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use $watch by keeping variable in both on change you will get event that they are completed with their execution

Comment: Are both methods can return promise ?

Comment: you can use `$q` to create the promise,  resolve it in iframeOnLoad function or wherever you want, and then use `$q.all([<promises>])` to combine these 2 promises into one. Next steps should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert `iframeOnload` to a Promise

```
$scope.iframeOnLoad = function(){
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
       ....on("iframeloadedEvent", function() {
            resolve("iframeloaded")
       })
  ...

$q.all([$scope.iframeOnload(), $scope.getPage()]
.then(magic)
```

For your further question, have a try with

```
var p1 = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    $scope.iframeOnLoad = function(obj) {
        resolve(obj);
    };
}

$q.all([p1, $scope.getPage]
.then(magic)
```

I feel uncomfortable setting iframeOnload like this within a closure, so I'm not sure whether it would work. Someone else might be able to offer a more elegant solution

Comment: Hi Simon, that would seem like the ideal situation. But I don't know how to do that, I've added the directive in the post above. Could you perhaps give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If your methods may return `promises` you can use Angulars `$q` service and method `all`.

Here is a simple excample of how to use it:

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MLJmOvr8YgYAgTd8TE3h?p=preview)

And here more about `$q` service:

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 0):

pass callback function to your services like

```
  myservice.getuser(data,function(response){
  //response data
});
```

in service

```
 getuser:function(data,callback)
{
 $http()
.success(response){callback(response)}
.failure(response){callback(response)}

}
```

or
you can use this

```
var deferred = $q.deferred();
  $http(api url and method)
    .success function() {
         deferred.resolve(); 
    }
    .failure function()  {
        deferred.reject(); 
    }
    return deferred.promise;
```